# React.memo Not Preventing Re-renders of Stateless Functional Child Component that Takes In No Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a stateless functional component (see **Title** below) that uses React-Reveal to display some simple heading elements on render. In addition to having no internal state, **Title** also doesn't receive any props from its parent component (**GameHeader**). But for some reason, **Title** still keeps getting re-rendered whenever I update the overall application state from another, unrelated component elsewhere in the tree and this is causing the React-Reveal animations to run every single time some unrelated app state changes.

```
// GameHeader.js
 
import React from 'react';
import Title from './Title';
import Options from './Options';
 
const GameHeader = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Title />
            <Options />
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default GameHeader;
 
 
// Title.js --> this component needs to stop re-rendering so much because it contains entrance animations
 
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Zoom from 'react-reveal/Zoom';
import Slide from 'react-reveal/Slide';
import Flip from 'react-reveal/Flip';
 
const Title = () => {
    console.log("Title rendering");
    const theme = useTheme();
 
    return (
        <>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="primary">
                <Slide left>Sample</Slide>
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h1" style={{ color: `${theme.palette.indigo.main}` }}>
                <Flip delay={800} duration={600} cascade>App</Flip>
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h2" style={{ color: `${theme.palette.orange.dark}` }}>
                <Zoom delay={1100} cascade>Title</Zoom>
            </Typography>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default React.memo(Title);
```

I've tried wrapping **Title** in React.memo or converting it to a PureComponent, but to no avail -- it still keeps needlessly re-rendering and re-triggering its animations. I am using hooks + the Context API (w/ useReducer & dispatch) to update my application state elsewhere in the app, but I am not consuming any of that state directly in **GameHeader** *or* **Title**.

I suspect that because React.memo/PureComponent only do a shallow compare between state & props, that maybe there is a phantom prop or something that is non-equivalent between renders that is still getting passed into **Title** somehow?? But I don't know why that would be, or how to confirm or address that. Or maybe I am just using React.memo incorrectly?

I understand that children re-rendering on parent state changes is just how React works, but I need a way to prevent my transitions from firing after unrelated state changes and React.memo doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Any thoughts?

Comment: If there's literally no props then the fact that `React.memo` does shallow comparisons would be irrelevant, since it's literally not comparing anything. One option here is that it's getting **remounted**, though without knowledge of the ancestor components or how they work we can't say. That would also make sense if the animations are only supposed to play *on mount*

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444. It does appear that it's getting remounted, because when I add a useEffect to "Title" with a console log statement and an empty dependency [] parameter, I am getting the console logged statement every time my state changes. I'm really not sure why this is happening, but I am combing back through all of the parent structures now to see if I can figure that out. In that case, I suppose React.memo will not help me either.

Comment: Yeah thought as much. Assuming you're not manually triggerring remounts by using something like a random `key` prop, then the answer will almost certainly be one of the ancestors somewhere up this component's tree is getting remounted. Will have to work your way up the tree find it, and debug that one. Should fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

Tracing it back up the tree got me to the solution. It turns out that the Material UI styled component wrappers I was using around **GameHeader** were causing **GameHeader** to remount every time, when I removed the styled component wrappers, **GameHeader** stopped remounting. Same thing with **Title**, though in the example I showed above, I had already removed the styled component wrapper from around that one.

These MUI styled component definitions were sitting inside my parent functional components (because they were making use of useTheme), so what I ended up doing was moving those MUI styled component definitions outside of the parent functional components (after the export default statement) and that, for whatever reason, completely resolved the issue.

Thanks @Jayce444 for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Im struggling with a similar problem where a component keeps re-rendering with react memo even though no props change, you mention you traced back up the tree, how did you do this? thanks.